# Можно ли сделать Вывод Системных Дисков на языке C ? (без библиотек)

Tags: c, ассемблер, inline

*Извиняюсь за столь непонятные вопросы*. Я пишу "os" на C для 32 бит I386. Хочу Сделать Функцию для вывода подключенных к компьютеру дисков, но знаний не хватает. Возможно ли вообще это как-то сделать? Bootloader компилирую в nasm. Заранее Спасибо)

Comment: Не хотите покопаться в какой-нибудь реальной ОС и посмотреть, что там и как? Они есть с открытым кодом...

Comment: @Harry спасибо за совет

Comment: Вот такую посмотрите: https://habr.com/ru/news/t/470832/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само понятие "диск" (C:,D: и т.п.) исключительно логическое и есть только в винде. В linux такого нет.
Задача в общем и целом не тривиальная. Вам надо изучить структуру MBR/GPT (для начала вот это прочтите https://www.minitool.com/lib/partition-table.html).
После того, как появится понимание, надо будет писать собственную реализацию чтения и разбора таблицы разделов, работу с файловыми системами и т.п. на уровне чтения/записи физических секторов дисков